# IE Child Action Redirect Issue MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We are developing a application in ASP.NET MVC5. 
I'm trying to redirect to some action(using RedirectToAction method) from a child action. It works in Firefox but it doesn't work in IE.
Any idea how i can get this to work with IE.

Code:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(VehicleGroup vehicleGroup)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cuser = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            vehicleGroup.User = cuser;
            db.VehicleGroups.Add(vehicleGroup);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            TempData["VG_Create"] = "Vehicle Group saved successfully.";

            return  RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return PartialView(vehicleGroup);
    }
```

**Edit:**

Actually I have a Index Action. In the index view, I have two parts. The left part show the list of existing Vehicle Groups and Right part contains the create form(Ajax Form).

[image]

Now when I create a new Vehicle Group I redirect the user to Index action. But It doesn't work in IE the page stays the same. While on Firefox it get redirected and i can see new data.

Comment: Expand on doesn't work in IE.  What happens?

Comment: Please check the edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me, the problem was the compatibility mode in IE.
Try to add the following in the _Layout

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Comment: Redirect works even in old IE like ie7 without this meta tag.