# View in ActionResult not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I have an `ActionResult` `SaveUploadedFile` and an `ActionResult` `Dashboard`. `SaveUploadedFile` redirects to `Action` `Dashboard`.

```
public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
{
     //Call to WEB API
     ...
     ...
     //On Success of API
     if (results.payload.success == true)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
     }

 throw new HttpException(403, "Something happened");

} 

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
     return View();
}
```

The `ActionResult XXX` is called from my HTML form.

```
 <form action="~/Home/SaveUploadedFile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm"></form>
```

The control reaches `ActionResult Dashboard` but the corresponding `Dashboard View` doesn't get rendered. `Dashboard` works perfectly when called from other `ActionResults`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the actual code?  What you are describing should work in theory.  t has to be something else.  For example, what exactly is contained  in the view that YYY is returning.   Have you looked at Fiddler for clues?

Comment: Also, what browser are you using.  There have been reported IE issues with RedirecttoAction in MVC 5 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096474/ie-child-action-redirect-issue-mvc

Comment: I'm working on Chrome 39.0.2171.71

Comment: OK.  But according to this code Dashboard is returning an empty view.  Is dashboard simply an HTML page with no controller information code going to it?   I am unsure how you are determining that it is not firing.  Also, what happens if results.payload.success is false and there is no exception thrown?

Comment: Your code appears t obe fine. Are you sure your condition (results.payload.success) is passing? And what is rendered? A blank page, a error?

Comment: the Dashbord view is just a static page as of now, which will have a model passed as a parameter in the future. The controll successfully reaches return view() in the Dashboard ActionResult. For some reason, only in this case, the page is not being refreshed. Redirection to the same dashboard from other ActionResults works perfectly and the view is refreshed.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading.  By your own admission, you are getting redirected to Dashboard.  So the Redirect is working just fine.  Your problem is that your view is not being rendered when you redirect for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This should expose what the issue is:

```
    public ActionResult SaveUploadedFile()
    {
         //Call to WEB API
         ...
         ...
         //On Success of API
         if (results.payload.success == true)
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
         } else {
        return RedirectToAction("AnotherAction");
}

     throw new HttpException(403, "Something happened");

    } 

    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
ViewData("test") = "Hello World";
         return View();
    }
```

In your Dashboard view put @ViewData("test") if you do not already have something to test that the view is rendering.